# What are the characteristics of the Geass power?

Tags: code-geass

When I recalled every type of Geass in the two seasons, I was asking myself what the characteristics of Geass are. For instance, I was wondering if every Geass power needs someone other than the Geass user (examples are Lelouch's Geass and Mao's Geass), but there were some people in the second season to whom the rule doesn't apply. (I don't know how much I can say without giving spoilers.) The effects of the Geass vary a lot, so I think I cannot find any attributes that are common for Geass-effects.

But are there some characteristics/rules/etc., which are the same for every Geass-power?

Comment: I edited your question for clarity and grammar. If I've somehow changed the meaning of something, feel free to edit that back in though.

Comment: @Maroon I noticed that and I am grateful. My english is (as you can clearly see) not the best and I am happy that someone corrected me so that other users can understnad what I am asking for. You did well and left the meaning of my question unchanged, well done.

Comment: @Sirac I'm pretty sure that the various Geass powers have nothing in common, other than that they manifest in the eyes of the users.

Comment: "_I was wondering if every Geass power needs someone other than the Geass user (examples are Lelouch's Geass and Mao's Geass)_" you sentence seems to cut off here, what do you mean _needs someone other than the Geass User_?

Comment: I'm writing up something of an answer, which might address @Memor-X.

Comment: @Maroon if i read that sentence correctly using your answer as a fall back Sirac is asking if all Geass powers affect another user?

Comment: @Memor-X my interpretation was more of "does usage fo the Geass require another _person_" when I first saw the question, which might have been wrong, but I figured that it made sense as a question since Rolo doesn't seem to necessarily require someone else per se.

Comment: I'm removing my answer - I realized from senshin's comment that I forgot about some other users, so the basic gist of my comment doesn't really seem right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some basic characteristics/rules/constraints that are common in all canon *Geass Users*

- **Their power can not affect Code Barer**: We see with with C.C when Lelouch tries to command her and Mao's obsession for C.C was given birth from the fact that her mind was the only one he could not read. Also Charles blocked Lelouch's order when his Code became active
- **Each use increases power**: Mao, Lelouch and C.C before she got the Code, use of their powers increased it's strength and thus they were unable to control it. Rolo while he was always in control of his power the same power stopped his heart. as the power got stronger we can assume that the strain on his heart got worse aswell, dying before it fully went out of control. the children
- **The Sigil manifests within the eye(s) when the power activates**: with all characters the Sigils appear in the eye(s) when the is used and remains in the eye(s) when the user no longer as control. Lelouch's sigil disappears when he lost control due to the Contacts he wore. C.C's uncontrolled Geass was lost when she received the Code. Bismark's power wasn't active all the time because he had his eye sown shut and the wiki seem to indicate he couldn't turn it off.
- **A user surrenders their powers when they obtain The Code**: When C.C gained the Code she was no longer able to user her power while Charles didn't use his power after the Code resurrected him. it's unsure if the Code being inactive or not causes a user to surrender their powers as when Lelouch was being careful not to be affected by Charles's power a second time however didn't know he had an inactive Code
- **A User's Power will isolate them**: if we look at all the user's powers, consent use would isolate them for society. Lelouch being able to get anyone to do anything he wants, Mao being able to always being able to read someone's true thoughts. the love C.C revived was always false love induced from her Geass and Code Barers being immortal. every power has the possibility of isolating someone from the rest of the world as we have seen in other fiction how disenchanted with the world one becomes if they could always see someones true thoughts, see the future or never receive unforced love.

This last point may or may not be true because of the Geass Order

- **Powers are unique**: we have seen that every character had a unique power. this however there are some contradictions to this,

  - **The children of the Geass Order** - they force a Black Knight Pilot to attack his allies, the [Wiki](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Geass#Unnamed_Children.27s_Geass) notes that it may be more puppetry
  - **Shin Hyuga Shaingu** - it's speculated that it works the same way as Lelouch's from the limited observations in Akito of the exiled

In these cases we are unsure who the Contractor (Code Barers) is. the only Code Barers who were in Britannia were all affiliated with the Geass Order (C.C and V.V were directors, Charles probably became defacto director after V.V's death) and because of the nature of the Order's research these power may have in fact be fabricated. this is plausible because of [Julius Kingsley](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Julius_Kingsley) as if he is Lelouch then Lelouch was not at Ashford the entire time in the 1 year gap and the fact that the emperor sent him with Suzaku (who too knew of Geass and possible the Order having been shown the Sword of Akasha) it is pleasurable that The Order could have studied Lelouch (the only exception to this if Julius is Lelouch's Twin Brother).

As for your comment

> I was wondering if every Geass power needs someone other than the Geass user

If by this you mean "*can Geass only affect another person who has does not have Geass or under the effects of someone else's Geass*" then no. in the First Season Lelouch uses a mirror to cast Geass on himself to make him forget about the plan to save Nunnally from Mao, this way Mao could not read his mind and detonate the bomb. Also Mao uses his power to read Lelouch's mind numerous times to see every move he would think up when they play chess and to discover he was Zero to break Shirley (though Mao had to focus hard in order to target Lelouch and not everyone else).

In the Second Season, Rolo uses his Geass on Lelouch in the OSS H.Q which is when Lelouch figured out that Rolo's Geass affect one's perception of time because Lelouch was counting the second on the clock before hand.

[Bismarck Waldstein's](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Bismarck_Waldstein) power is to "see the future" however we only uses this in combat when he uses it on Suzaku while he mentioned to have used it on Marianne. his powers isn't fully explained however we can assume he sees the future of "Cause and Effect" so when he uses it on Suzaku he sees the Before Images of Suzaku's piloting of the Lancelot. Suzaku use the Geass put on him to "Live" to overpower Bismarck's power.

And of cause there is Charles who wiped Lelouch's memories after the first season with his Geass and Lelouch was able to order him to kill himself at the Sword of Akasha (before hte Code Activated). there is also suspicion that non human entities can be affected like when Lelouch orders "God" however i have speculation on just what happened here.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. When you asked what I meant with "I was wondering if every Geass power needs someone other than the Geass user" I meant that the Geass power would be useless for the user if he was all alone (Lelouch could use his power on himself once, Rolo's Geass would be useless as well as Charles' Geass), but that point is unclear because there are exceptions (like Bismarck's Geass).

Comment: @Sirac hmmmm, Lelouch used his Geass on himself however he did that to get passed Mao's Geass. Charles and C.C may have been able to reflect their own Geass back at them but it then comes down to what good if any could come from it, C.C would be forced to love herself and Charles could rewrite his own memories or seal his own Geass.

Comment: Weather or not a Geass Power is usable when the user is alone will be dependent on the power. so far we have yet to see a canon Geass Power which could

Comment: Arguablely Waldstein's power could fall into that category, but without further information it's hard to tell for sure.